# How to get Trac (CommitTicketUpdater) w/Mercurial to close|resolve tickets on commit?

Tags: python, mercurial, trac

***My Quick Question is this:*** *Everything seems to be working, except that Trac tickets don't get status updates upon commit. Change-set notes are appended to the ticket, but the tickets themselves are not being resolved*

---

I've just done this setup:

> - Windows 7 x64
> - IIS 7.5
> - isapi-wsgi 0.4.2
> - Python27 32
> - Mercurial 1.8
> - Trac 0.12

I've got Trac running and linked up with the repo (I can view the changesets, browse etc)
I'm using AD for auth, so all my usernames are in this format: ***MYDOMAIN\bbarker***

Setup the ***CommitTicketUpdater*** following the instructions *[here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater)*.

When I commit new code, and link to a ticket:

> `$ hg commit -m "[fixes #1] - blah blah blah..."`
>   `$ hg push`

Trac appends a change-set to the ticket:

> Changed 5 seconds ago by MYDOMAIN\bbarker
>     In [29283792837498273948729374]:
>     [fixes #1] - blah blah blah...

*(The **#1**, above, is a link to the ticket)*
**But the ticket status is never updated**, no matter what I try.
Is there anything additional I need to be doing to get this to work?

*below are snippets of my settings*

---

**trac.ini**

> [components]
>   tracext.hg.* = enabled
>   tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.* = enabled
>   tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketreferencemacro = enabled
>   tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketupdater = enabled
>
> [hg]
>   node_format = short
>   show_rev = yes
>
> [ticket]
>   ...
>   commit_ticket_update_envelope = []
>   commit_ticket_update_commands.close =
>   commit_ticket_update_commands.refs = <ALL>
>   commit_ticket_update_check_perms = true
>   commit_ticket_update_notify = true
>
> [trac]
>   ... 
>   repository_dir = C:\repositories\project
>   repository_sync_per_request = default
>   repository_type = hg

**.hg/hgrc**

> [hooks]
>   ; If mercurial-plugin is installed in a Trac plugins directory
>   commit = python:C:\Trac\hooks.py:add_changesets
>   changegroup = python:C:\Trac\hooks.py:add_changesets
>
> [trac]
>   env = C:\Trac\tracproject
>   trac-admin = C:\Python27\Scripts\trac-admin.exe

Comment: After struggling with Trac for a whole month a few years back, I found that the best way to get Trac working properly is to use Redmine instead. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phew! Got it...

Following, to the 'T', the directions from the [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater) site was my error.
Well kind of, I guess.

I had, basically, copied this from the above site into my *trac.ini* file:

> commit_ticket_update_envelope = []
>   **commit_ticket_update_commands.close =**
>   commit_ticket_update_commands.refs = 
>   commit_ticket_update_check_perms = true
>   commit_ticket_update_notify = true

Reading the below I just assumed that leaving the **commit_ticket_update_commands.close** to an empty value would assume defaults.
This actually overwrites the defaults to an empty value, which explains why none of the commands worked, yet my commit messages were still being appended to the corresponding tickets.

So simply removing, or commenting out, that line in the .ini resolved my problem
*(or, didn't override the defaults)*

> commit_ticket_update_envelope = []
>   **;commit_ticket_update_commands.close =**
>   commit_ticket_update_commands.refs = 
>   commit_ticket_update_check_perms = true
>   commit_ticket_update_notify = true

So after some debugging, testing, web scouring, I really just needed to re-look at the instructions provided by Trac. It's pretty obvious looking back on it now :)